# Linking error using cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, linker, pthreads

I'm compiling some code using cmake, and encountered error. This is the message I got:

```
[ 79%] Linking CXX executable ../release/report_intr_dim
/usr/bin/ld: ../release/libNonMetricSpaceLib.a(pivot_neighb_invindx.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/build.make:99: recipe for target 'release/report_intr_dim' failed
make[2]: *** [release/report_intr_dim] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:326: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Makefile:127:

```
[126]all: cmake_check_build_system
[127]        $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/safarisoul/nns_benchmark-master/algorithms/NMSLIB/code/CMakeFiles /home/safarisoul/nns_benchmark-master/algorithms/NMSLIB/code/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
[128]        $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
[129]        $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/safarisoul/nns_benchmark-master/algorithms/NMSLIB/code/CMakeFiles 0
[130].PHONY : all
```

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:326:

```
[323]# All Build rule for target.
[324]test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/all: lshkit/CMakeFiles/lshkit.dir/all
[325]test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/all: src/CMakeFiles/NonMetricSpaceLib.dir/all
[326]        $(MAKE) -f test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/build.make test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/depend
[327]        $(MAKE) -f test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/build.make test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/build
[328]        @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --progress-dir=/home/safarisoul/nns_benchmark-master/algorithms/NMSLIB/code/CMakeFiles --progress-num=93,94 "Built target report_intr_dim"
[329].PHONY : test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/all
[330]
[331]# Include target in all.
[332]all: test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/all
[333]
[334].PHONY : all
```

test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/build.make:99:

```
[88]# External object files for target report_intr_dim
[89]report_intr_dim_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS =
[90]
[91]release/report_intr_dim: test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/report_intr_dim.cc.o
[92]release/report_intr_dim: test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/build.make
[93]release/report_intr_dim: release/libNonMetricSpaceLib.a
[94]release/report_intr_dim: release/liblshkit.a
[95]release/report_intr_dim: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
[96]release/report_intr_dim: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so
[97]release/report_intr_dim: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so
[98]release/report_intr_dim: test/CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/link.txt
[99]        @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=/home/safarisoul/nns_benchmark-master/algorithms/NMSLIB/code/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_2) "Linking CXX executable ../release/report_intr_dim"
[100]       cd /home/safarisoul/nns_benchmark-master/algorithms/NMSLIB/code/test && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/report_intr_dim.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
```

I did a google search, and realised that I need to add '-pthread' somewhere, and I should probably modify something in [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/DBWangGroupUNSW/nns_benchmark/blob/master/algorithms/NMSLIB/code/CMakeLists.txt). But this is my first time using cmake, and I'm not familar with c/c++. I have no idea what to do to fix this problem. Please help.

Comment: "I did a google search, and realised that I need to add '-pthread' somewhere, and I should probably modify something in CMakeLists.txt." - Exactly. Report that problem to the project's developers. (Here we could help you to fix **your code**, if you are able to minimize it to show the problem. But fixing *other's projects* isn't a purpose of Stack Overflow. You show makefiles which are *generated*. But the problem is in **one of** `CMakeLists.txt` files.)

Comment: you probably don't `target_link_libraries` against pthread

Comment: Show us your `CMakeLists.txt`, please.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is really linking with pthread which is missing, this is the current way how it should be done in a CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
[..]
target_link_libraries(target [SCOPE] Threads::Threads)
```

Answer (score 1):

To link `pthreads` using `CMake`:

`find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(NonMetricSpaceLib Threads::Threads)`

If you have multiple thread libraries, you can try setting `CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD` and `THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG`.

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html